# Android respond only to a Sub-URI

Tags: android

My App is able to respond to any link in the browser visiting example.com with the following code. My question is, how can I program my app only to respond to

```
"http://example.com/#push/...".
```

I have to implement it this way, because only if the link contains the specific path, it should be possible to open the link with my app. Not in general. Another possible solution would be to allow any URI, but that one. So my App respond to any link but one.

```
            <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I tried to add a pathPattern, but that results in not opening the link anymore:

```
<data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*push.*"
                android:scheme="http" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with

```
<data
     android:host="example.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/#push/"
     android:scheme="http" />
```

This way you can check only the initial part of the path.
Remember to include the leading / since it is a path segment.

The official documentation has a couple of examples on using the  element:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html